# Where to put a file to read from a class under a package in java?

Tags: java, file-io, file-read, filepath

I have a properties file contains the file name only say `file=fileName.dat`. I've put the properties file under the class path and could read the file name(file.dat) properly from it in the `mainClass`. After reading the file name I passed the file name(just name not the path) to another class under a package say `pack.myClass` to read that file. But the problem is `pack.myClass` could not get the file path properly. I've put the file `fileName.dat` both inside and outside the package`pack` but couldn't make it work.

Can anybody suggest me that where to put the file `fileName.dat` so I can read it properly and the whole application would be portable too.

Thanks!

The code I'm using to read the config file and getting the file name:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = mainClass.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
prop.load(in);
in.close();

myClass mc = new myClass();
mc.readTheFile(prop.getProperty("file"));
/*until this code is working good*/
```

Then in `myClass` which is under package named `pack` I am doing:

```
public void readTheFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename); /*this couldn't get the file whether i'm putting the file inside or outside the package folder */
    /*after reading the file I've to do the BufferReader for further operation*/
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
```

Comment: Please provide us with the code, as well as the runtime system (Java 2 SE?) and indicate the user of the application

Comment: @owlstead: I've edited my question with the code i'm working

Comment: @JBNizet: I've edited my question with the code i'm working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to read properties file using getResource method of class. If you put properties file on root of the classpath you should prefix file name with '/' to indicate root of classpath, for example getResource("/file.dat"). If properties file is under the same folder with the class you on which you invoke getResource method, than you should not use '/' prefix.

Comment: getResourceAsStream and FileReader uses completely different strategies to locate file. getResourceAsStream searches file in classpath, FileReader searches file in file system path. They are different, stick to only one strategy.

Comment: if i use getResourceAsStream can I pass that to the BufferReader I'm doing in the next line?

Comment: you should be able to do something like new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(xxxClass.getResorceAsStream("give path relative to xxxClass or root of Classpath with / prefix"))

Answer (score 1):

When you use a relative file name such as `fileName.dat`, you're asking for a file with this name in the *current directory*. The current directory has nothing to do with packages. It's the directory from which the JVM is started.

So if you're in the directory `c:\foo\bar` when you launch your application (using `java -cp ... pack.MyClass`), it will look for the file `c:\foo\bar\fileName.dat`.

Answer (score 1):

Try..

```
myClass mc = new myClass();
InputStream in = mc.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/pack/config.properties");
```

..or simply

```
InputStream in = mc.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

..for the last line if the `main` is in `myClass`  The class loader available in the `main()` will often be the bootstrap class-loader, as opposed to the class-loader intended for application resources.

Comment: I can read the properties file as I told and could pass the filename to the mc.readTheFile(). It can get the filename but I need to know that what will be great place to put the file filename.dat so readTheFle() can read the file and the whole process will be portable so that I can do the whole job using just class files which will automatically locate the filename.dat

Comment: Stop thinking of it as a 'file', if it is inside the application Jar, it is **not** a normal `File`, and cannot be written to.  It **can** be located and read by `URL` or `InputStream` though.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it would be best to look for the `"fileName.dat"` somewhere in the `"user.home"` folder, which is a [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). First create a `File` path from the `"user.home"` and then try to find the file there. This is a bit of a guess as you don't provide the exact user of the application, but this would be the most common place.

You are currently reading from the current folder which is determined by

```
String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
```

or

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Comment: please have a look in my question with the edited portion with the code i'm working

Comment: changed my answer accordingly, it still depends on your "use case" if this is correct

Answer (score 0):

Class.getResource will look in your package directory for a file of the specified name.

[JavaDocs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

Or getResourceAsStream is sometimes more convenient as you probably want to read the contents of the resource.

Answer (score 0):

To read a file, even from within a jar archive:

```
readTheFile(String package, String filename) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    String filepath = package+"/"+filename;  
    // like "pack/fileName.dat" or "fileName.dat"

    String s = (new SourceBase()).getSourceBase() + filepath;
    URL url = new URL(s);
    InputStream ins = url.openStream();
    BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins, "utf8"));
    do {
        s = rdr.readLine();
        if(s!= null) System.out.println(s);
    }
    while(s!=null);
    rdr.close(); 
 }
```

with

```
class SourceBase
{
    public String getSourceBase()
    {
    String cn = this.getClass().getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
    // like "packagex/SourceBase.class"

    String s = this.getClass().getResource('/' + cn).toExternalForm();
    // like "file:/javadir/Projects/projectX/build/classes/packagex/SourceBase.class"
    // or "jar:file:/opt/java/PROJECTS/testProject/dist/
    //                testProject.jar!/px/SourceBase.class"

    return s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(cn));
    // like "file:/javadir/Projects/projectX/build/classes/"
    // or "jar:file:/opt/java/PROJECTS/testProject/dist/testProject.jar!/"
    }
}
```