# Dealing with getResourceAsStream for outside file

Tags: java, directory, inputstream

I'm having a problem with getResourceAsStream method - it returns null because of wrong directory. The problem is that I do not have an idea how to define the dir.

My project structure looks like that

```
Project
  #src
    #com.package
      #ExampleClass.java
  #dll
    #MyFile.dll
```

When I have

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../dll/" + "MyFile.dll");
```

It returns null. Do anyone have an idea how to deal with this problem and how the path schould be defined?

Answer (score 3):

If `this` is `ExampleClass` in `com.package` package, you need to go two levels up to reach the root of the CLASSPATH:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../dll/" + "MyFile.dll");
```

Assuming `/dll` directory is placed directly in the root of your CLASSPATH. Or simply use absolute path:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dll/" + "MyFile.dll");
```

If the `/dll/MyFile.dll` is not on yout CLASSPATH (just open your JAR file and check whether it's there) you should use file system mechanisms to open it.

Comment: "../../dll/" thats what I did but it didin't help. How to configure CLASSPATH in eclipse?

Comment: @MisterS: I am not using Eclipse, but check out: http://openscada.org/2010/05/31/adding-a-directory-as-class-path-to-eclipse/ or Google "*eclipse classpath add directory*"

Comment: Open project properties, search java build path. Add dll folder in source tab and write a suitable ouput folder path.If you enter dll as output folder, use getResourceAsStream("/dll ......")

Comment: @Deniz - I've done what u suggested and it look like on the screen http://clip2net.com/s/25V6H but it doesn't work... Do u have any other idea?

Comment: Ok, problem solved ;) I used this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(mylib.dll) and add folder dll to java.library.path

Comment: @MisterS: if you added `/dll/mylib.dll` to `java.library.path` you probably had to use `getResourceAsStream(/dll/mylib.dll)`. Also now: `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dll/MyFile.dll");` should also work (or `"/MyFile.dll"` for that matter). Please accept some of the two answers or write your own and self-accept it to instruct future visitors (your advice will be lost in comments).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on location of MyFile.dll in classpath, not location of MyFile.dll onyour project. Please take a look at [where to put a file to read from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273064/where-to-put-a-file-to-read-from-a-class-under-a-package-in-java/11273135#11273135)