# Loading a dll file into a java class

Tags: java, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-code, java-native-interface

I'm trying to load a `.dll` file into my java class `OpenDmx.java` which is named `opendmx.dll` in the directory `/Users/ethan/Desktop/LightingConsole/opendmx.dll`.

As you can see I have tried `System.loadLibrary()` and `System.setProperty()`. Also not pictured I have tried `System.load()`.

I have no clue what to try next and any help would be appreciated.

**CODE**

```
static {
     System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/Users/ethan/Desktop/LightingConsole");
     System.loadLibrary("opendmx");
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opendmx in java.library.path
[/Users/ethan/Library/Java/Extensions, /Library/Java/Extensions, /Network/Library/Java/Extensions, /System/Library/Java/Extensions, /usr/lib/java, .]
```

Then I tried:

```
java -agentpath:"/Users/ethan/Desktop/LightingConsole/opendmx.dll"
```

Which gave me the error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library /Users/ethan/Desktop/LightingConsole/opendmx.dll in absolute path, with error: dlopen(/Users/ethan/Desktop/LightingConsole/opendmx.dll, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/ethan/Desktop/LightingConsole/opendmx.dll: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x50 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00
        /Users/ethan/Desktop/LightingConsole/opendmx.dll: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x50 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

Comment: you could  try to use `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(your dll)` and add folder dll to `java.library.path`,refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11345709/10768653 and the coments in it

Comment: Try passing `-Djava.library.path=...` to your first `java` invocation. It is possible that the path is read at startup.

Comment: Also, as you seem to be on macOS, it is looking for `libopendmx.dylib`. The fact that it was named `.dll` worries me: you cannot simply drop a Windows DLL on a macOS machine and expect it to work.

Comment: @Botje Thanks for your comment!  That's what I was afraid of.  What would you suggest I do since I can't load a Windows DLL on macOS?  Is there a way I can convert a `.dll` to a `.dylib`?  If there is please include a link.

Comment: No, you cannot simply convert code compiled for windows into a macOS library. A quick search found that you can use [libftdi](https://www.openlighting.org/ola/getting-started/device-specific-configuration/#Open_DMX_USB_FTDI_RS485), but the interface will obviously be different.